# How to make an array that each number in it stores one string like const char * argv[ ] does?

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to make an array that each number of array can store one string, same as what const char * argv[ ] does.

So for the following code,

```
cout << array[0] << endl;
cout << array[1] << endl;
```

can produce for example,

```
David
Jason
```

So each number in an array actually store a string. I wonder how to do this, what type should I put for the array.

Comment: Use `char**`, the same of `argv`. In other terms, if you want the same, use the same.

Comment: In the future you should avoid asking such basic questions as "how do I make an array" and instead _read your introductory C++ book_.

Comment: @skypjack: That's misleading. It suggests that a `char**` is an array. It is not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may form array of pointers to char.

```
const char* array[] = { "David",
                        "Jason" };
```

or in dynamically allocated memory

```
char** array = new char*[2];
array[0] = "David";
array[1] = "Jason";
```

Answer (score 0):

> what type should I put for the array.

Well, if you want the same behaviour as `argv`, then the same type as `argv` is one option.

However, realistically and in general, the only acceptable way to create an array of strings in 2015 is the following:

```
std::array<std::string, N> myArray;
```

where `N` is the number of elements you want.